# JavaScript While loop not working

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

I have been trying to develope javascript to recognise a name, display the name, its length and the the letters and what position they appear but i cannot seem to get the while loop to work. could someone please help me out, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html >
<head>
    <title>
        javascript
    </title>
    <script>
        function displayName(){

        var str = prompt("enter your name:");
        var len = str.length;
        var chara = str.charAt(0);
        var n = chara.indexOf(0);


        while(chara <= len){
                document.write("<br>the letter " + chara + " is number " + n);
                chara++;
            }

           document.write("the name entered is: " + str + "<br></br>" + "the length is " +  len);

            }

     </script>


</head>
  <body>

     <script>
      displayName();    
     </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, add a node (`<p>` or similar) and update that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your loop is using the wrong iterator.

```
function displayName(){

    var str = prompt("enter your name:");
    var len = str.length;
    var chara = 0;

    while(chara < len){
        document.write("<br>the letter " + str.charAt(chara) + " is number " + (chara + 1));
        chara++;
    }

    document.write("<br/>the name entered is: " + str + "<br></br>" + "the length is " +  len);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `chara` set to the first character, "A" for example. Then you try to do `while A <= 4` (assuming length is 4), which will never be true. `chara` needs to be a number for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting `chara` to the first character of the returned string. Try setting it to 0

`var chara = 0;`

and see if that works.

Comment: Well of course. But I wasn't going to rewrite it for him; just answer the given question.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the wrong variable.  Instead of incrementing `chara`, you should increment `n` and reset `chara` to point to the next character of your string.  You are also using `indexOf` improperly - just set `n = 0;` to start with

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is comparing a character (the first character of the name) to a number (the length of the name). There are a few ways to approach the task you are trying to accomplish.

If you want to keep using a while loop, you should keep track of a variable that serves as a counter, which counts which iteration of the loop you are on. This would replace the chara variable.

[here is a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/cn0gx89j/)

```
function displayName(){

    var str = prompt("enter your name:");
    var len = str.length;
    var count = 0;


    while(count < len){
        document.body.innerHTML += "<br>the letter " + str.charAt(count) + " is number " + (count+1);
        count++;
    }

    document.body.innerHTML += "<br>the name entered is: " + str + "<br></br>" + "the length is " +  len;

}
```

I've replaced the calls to `document.write()` with the `innerHTML` parameter because it is considered better practice, but you can use either.

As an aside, it would be more semantic to use a for loop for this task.